# Changing database name in config file

Tags: php, laravel, config

I want to change config database value in `bootstrap/app.php`.
I found function to do this: `config(['database.default' => 'mysql2'])` but I have that error: `Fatal error: Uncaught ReflectionException: Class config does not exist in C:\xampp\htdocs\project\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php:779 Stack trace: #0`

`C:\xampp\htdocs\project\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php(779): ReflectionClass->__construct('config') #1`

`C:\xampp\htdocs\project\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php(658): Illuminate\Container\Container->build('config') #2`

`C:\xampp\htdocs\project\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php(609): Illuminate\Container\Container->resolve('config', Array) #3`

`C:\xampp\htdocs\project\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Application.php(759): Illuminate\Container\Container->make('config', Array) #4`

`C:\xampp\htdocs\project\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\helpers.php(121): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->make('config', Array) #5`

`C:\xampp\htdocs\project\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\helpers.php(280): app('config') #6`

`C:\xampp\htdocs\project\bootstrap\a in C:\xampp\htdocs\project\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php on line 779`

My version of laravel is 5.7. I tried to add facade `use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Config` but it didn't help.
How do this properly?

Comment: you don't need to touch that bootstrap file and it isn't the right place to do that ... if you are editing a project file to change the database configuration why don't you just edit the actual config file for the database, `config/database.php`? or use the `.env` file to set the value

Comment: Because I want to change database depends from subdomain. I find that bootstrap/app.php is place to change it and it had works when I was swapping `.env` files.
Edit:
I don't want change .env file because I want use config cache.

Comment: no bootstrap is not the place ... the framework hasn't even booted yet

Comment: using the `.env` file doesn't stop you from having a cached config ... you can't use the `env` helper function outside of config files .. that is all

Comment: Ok, so where would be good place to change it and how use `config(['database.default' => 'mysql2']) ` function, I just want to know that?

Comment: the `.env` file or environmental variable how ever they are set in your setup .. you can use the config method any time after the framework has booted

Comment: config(['database.default' => 'mysql2']) put this in your routes file, you cant put that in bootstrap/app.php because the app is not boot yet

Comment: dont put it in the routes file, that is also not where that belongs .... the route files do not always get parsed (route caching)

Comment: so I should write provider and add it on the end of providers list in `config/app.php `?

Answer (score 1):

This seems like an x/y problem. You are asking for help changing the database name, but the real problem you are trying to solve is dynamically choosing a database based on subdomain.

It feels like you are possibly looking for a clean way to do multitenanacy? I suggest you think carefully about that problem as a whole. There are a number of packages which help with this problem, such as https://docs.spatie.be/laravel-multitenancy/v1/introduction/ . I recommend you look at that project and other laravel multitenant projects. Even if you don't directly use one of them, you can learn a lot about strategies for approaching multitenancy from them.

Answer (score 0):

To change ur database configuration..you can do that through the .env file
whatever you set the